# How to save user input linebreak to database. (jQuery/php/mysql)

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

The question is: 
**How to save user input linebreak to database. (jQuery/php/mysql)**

I have a paragraph which is editable by the user.

```
<p contenteditable="true" id="forbiddenField">Text</p>
```

When I retrieve data from db with this:

```
<p contenteditable="true" id="forbiddenField"><?php echo nl2br($forbidden); ?></p>
```

and that works great.

onblur (.blur) will activate a jQuery script which will send the new edited data to a database.

```
$("#forbiddenField").blur(function(){
        var whatIsNowForbidden = encodeURI($("#forbiddenField").text());

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",  
            url: "updateForbidden.php",  
            data: "forbiddenStuff="+ whatIsNowForbidden,
            success: function(){
            }  
        });
});
```

**Problem:**
If the user inserts new data, with linebreaks, then the linebreaks are not added to the data in the database, only the content is added.

I tried this among other things:
var whatIsNowForbidden = encodeURI($("#forbiddenField").text());

I looked at theese places for answers:
[New Line in Textarea to be converted to <br/>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999792/new-line-in-textarea-to-be-converted-to-br)
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp
[Is replacing a line break UTF-8 safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3902451/is-replacing-a-line-break-utf-8-safe)
[how to escape input but save unescaped into the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6631270/how-to-escape-input-but-save-unescaped-into-the-database)
[How to recognize every linebreak?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3242211/how-to-recognize-every-linebreak)

I can't get it to work. 
All input and hints are much appreciated!

Comment: First things first: Are you sure the carriage return's aren't being saved in the database? Also, how are you making your paragraph (`<p></p>`) editable?

Comment: What takes the space of the linebreaks? Spaces? Tabs? Nothing?

Comment: contenteditable="true" inside the <p> makes it editable :)

Comment: May I ask what:  "carriage return's"  means?

Comment: also not sure what you mean by "What takes the space of the linebreaks?"

If i do an alert(); of the value of the paragraf I get:
alert(encodeURI($("#forbiddenField").text()));

The text: 
Föbjudet: allt som inte är tillåtet. (Forbidden: All that is not allowed)

Another line down here.

gives:
F%C3%B6bjudet:%20allt%20som%20inte%20%C3%A4r%20till%C3%A5tet.%20(Forbidden:%20All%20that%20is%20not%20allowed)Another%20line%20down%20here.

Comment: A carriage return is a control characater that, when used toghether with the line feed character, represents the beginning of a new line (See more here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return). Could you perhaps show us the website where we can see the input and output behaviour of the application? Also, your URL encoding function is not representing the line feeds (%0A), if you're using that function to save it's output on the database that might be the problem right there.

Comment: Looking to your code again, the `encodeURI()` function might well be the problem. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the `encodeURI()` function from your javascript, like so:

```
var whatIsNowForbidden = $("#forbiddenField").text();
```

I made a fiddle to test this and javascript's `encodeURI()` function doesn't seem to translate the new lines made in the paragraph to `%0A`, like we were expecting to.

By removing the function `encodeURI()` PHP should be able to save the text, including new lines, to the database. And then, PHP's `nl2br()` should transform the new lines into `<br />` tag's with no problem.

The fiddle is available here: http://jsfiddle.net/LN7QC/

**Final answer:** use `<textarea>`

The jQuery:

```
$("#forbiddenField").blur(function(){
        var whatIsNowForbidden = $("#forbiddenField").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",  
            url: "updateForbidden.php",  
            data: "forbiddenStuff="+ whatIsNowForbidden,
            success: function(){
            }  
        });
});
```

adding to database:

```
<?php
    include('connect.php');

            if($_POST['forbiddenStuff']){
                $forbiddenInput = $_POST['forbiddenStuff'];
            }


    If($forbiddenInput){
        mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
        $changeDataInDB = "UPDATE heroes_and_helpers SET forbidden='$forbiddenInput' WHERE name ='sabina'";
        mysql_query($changeDataInDB);

    }
?>
```

fetching from database:

```
   mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
    $fetchForbidden = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM heroes_and_helpers WHERE name='sabina'");

        if (!$fetchForbidden)
          {
          die('Ngt ar fel: ' . mysql_error());
          }

    $whatIsForbidden = mysql_fetch_array($fetchForbidden); 
    $forbidden = $whatIsForbidden['forbidden'];
```

on the site:

```
<textarea id="forbiddenField" style="width: 450px; height: 500px;"><?php echo $forbidden; ?></textarea>
```

Comment: It didn't work for me. Does it matter that I'm working on localhost?

Comment: It shouldn't matter. Might we see the updateForbidden.php file code?

Comment: <?php
    include('connect.php');
            if($_POST['forbiddenStuff']){
                $forbiddenInput = $_POST['forbiddenStuff'];
            }

    If($forbiddenInput){
        mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
        $changeDataInDB = "UPDATE heroes_and_helpers SET forbidden='$forbiddenInput' WHERE name ='sabina'";
        mysql_query($changeDataInDB);      
    }
?>

Comment: How about if you echo the value of `nl2br($forbiddenInput);` directly, without passing through the database, will it work?

Comment: Also, try to change the paragraph to a `<textarea></textarea>`... I'm getting some really weird behavior from the paragraph. `encodeURI()` seems to encode the newlines in a textarea, but not in the paragraph. http://jsfiddle.net/LN7QC/1/

Comment: Everything works great with <textarea>.
I was hoping to get to use html5 ("contenteditable" :D).

I had to remove all nl2br when using <textarea></textarea>

Comment: You're welcome! Just a final observation, you should sanitize your SQL query before executing it to prevent [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). You can use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or, a faster alternative, using the `mysqli_real_escape_string()` function. For example: `$changeDataInDB = "UPDATE heroes_and_helpers SET forbidden='"+mysqli_real_escape_string($forbiddenInput)+"' WHERE name ='sabina'";`. Glad I could help!